# How to draw a representative gaussian random walk?

Tags: data-visualization, random-walk

I would like to draw (as in, with a pen on paper) a line chart that is representative of a Guassian random walk defined as the sequence of random variables $(Y_t)$ where $t = 0, 1, 2, \dots$, such that for $t \geq 0$, $Y_{t+1} = Y_t + \epsilon_t$, $\epsilon_t\sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and $Y_0 = 0$. That is, start at $y = 0$, and to find the $y$-position at every subsequent integer time-step, draw a variate from the standard normal distribution and add it to the current position.

Here is my attempt:
[image: plot of gaussian random walk]

I am not sure whether this is a good drawing or not. How should a visualisation of a random walk be constructed?

For example, [one study](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Polya/07468342.di020742.02p0021g.pdf) that asked people to write down sequences of coin tosses found that people underestimate the number of times the same toss comes up in a row. Two quotes from the study:

> Can you decide, in sixty seconds or less, which of the sequences is more likely to have arisen from actual coin tossing and which one is the imposter?

and

> In students' simulated patters, the longest run of consecutive heads or consecutive tails is almost invariable *too short* relative to that which tendsto arise from actual coin tossing.